# find when keys are unkown in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document structure like this

```
{  
   "storeId":"WES-1234",
   "items":{  
      "PA-001":{  
         "name":"Cheetos Flamin' Hot",
         "qty":5,
         "inbound":7
      },
      "QX-7785":{  
         "name":"Kraft Handi Snack",
         "qty":7,
         "inbound":0
      }
   }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is to search `items` whose `name` contains "Nabisco". How do I do this? As you all can see, `items` is a map, not list.
Mongo is version 2.6

so, in the collection, the document structure is like that, and I want to know which stores have at least 3 Nabiscos or 4 Cheetos, etc

PA-001 and QX-7785 are item codes, they are generated dynamically and thus, their values are not fixed or known ahead of time

Is there a way to query this structure? javascript is fine, so long it can achieve the query that I need.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your document.  What are `PA-001` , `QX-7785` ... are they a common field for all items or a value. I couldn't think of a scenario where you could have this kind of document structure.

Comment: yes, this is legacy structure, and these are item codes, so, there's no predicting what the next item code would look like

Answer (score 1):

my mongo db version is v4.0.0, in mongo console:

```
db.test.find({"items.PA-001.name": /Nabisco/})
```

if it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: yes, I know that would work, but the case here is the field name is unpredictable, since PA-001 and QZ-775 are al litem codes that are generated dynamically, so, the values are not fixed or known ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

@sprintone, change your document structure to something like this :

```
{  
  "storeId":"WES-1234",
  "items":[{  
     "reference": "PA-001",  
     "name": "Cheetos Flamin' Hot",
     "qty":5,
     "inbound":7
  }, ...]
}
```

That way you'll be able to perform Array's specific queries ($elemMatch ...) but also use reference as a "foreignKey" to perform lookup. It will be much more flexible that way !

Comment: cant be changed now, since the data already like this, there's already plan to migrate this, but as of now, we still need to query this document